# Nullpointer exception is being thrown while setText is being used within CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am using the following code to set text in `getView` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //inflate the view for each row of listview
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        view.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Statius");
    return view;
}
```

But the following error is being thrown

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.vaighai.adapters.RatingAdapter.getView(RatingAdapter.java:71)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
```

This points to the line where I am setting the text as `mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Statius");`

Why null pointer exception is being thrown though I have initialized the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: show your xml code of R.layout.rating_item

Comment: Try declaring `view` and `mViewHolder` inside `getView` method, not globally. It might be keeping older reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if mViewHolder.mstatus is null.
    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
might return null.